# How to connect to different node using geth?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have created two instances.One for local server and another for AWS server.

I have install `Geth/v1.4.18-stable-ef9265d0/linux/go1.7.1` in local server and `Geth/v1.6.7-stable-ab5646c5/linux-amd64/go1.8.1` installed in AWS server.

How to connect this two node using geth ?

Comment: use admin.addNode("enode://<id>@<ip_address>:<port>")

Answer (score 2):

You can find the enodeId of one of the nodes using `admin.nodeInfo`. Then open the console of other node and add the first node using `admin.addNode("<enodeId>@<ip>:<port>")`. You can find enodeId and port of the first node from `admin.nodeInfo`.